# Rails Persist Search Results to CSV Output

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search, activerecord, export-to-csv

I have a Rails 3.2.x app where I have a reporting controller that does search on the Call model.  The code I put together works fine and allows for multiple conditions that will display on the page.  The problem I'm having is with exporting the specific search results to a CSV file.  So far I've only been able to export the entire database to CSV instead of the specific search results.

I'd like to figure out how to get my search params to persist and be able to export only those records to CSV.

Here is my relevant code:

reports_controller.rb

```
  def index    
     @calls = Call.report(params[:search])
     respond_to do |format|
         format.html do
           @calls = @calls.paginate(:per_page => params[:per_page] || 10, :page => params[:page]).order('incident_number ASC')
         end
         format.csv { send_data @calls.to_csv }
         format.xls  { send_data @calls.to_csv(col_sep: "\t") }
       end
   end
```

Call.rb

```
def self.report(search)
    search ||= { type: "all" }

    # Determine which scope to search by
    results = case search[:type]
              when "open"
                open_status
              when "canceled"
                cancel
              when "closed"
                closed
              when "waitreturn"
                waitreturn
              when "wheelchair"
                wheelchair
              else
                scoped
              end

    results = results.by_unit_name(search[:unit_name]) if search[:unit_name].present?
    results = results.by_service_level(search[:service_level]) if search[:service_level].present?
    results = results.from_facility(search[:transferred_from]) if search[:transferred_from].present?
    results = results.to_facility(search[:transferred_to]) if search[:transferred_to].present?

    # If searching with BOTH a start and end date
    if search[:start_date].present? && search[:end_date].present?
      results = results.search_between(Date.parse(search[:start_date]), Date.parse(search[:end_date]))

      # If search with any other date parameters (including none)
    else
      results = results.search_by_start_date(Date.parse(search[:start_date])) if search[:start_date].present?
      results = results.search_by_end_date(Date.parse(search[:end_date])) if search[:end_date].present?
    end

    results
  end

 def self.to_csv(options = {})
    CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
      csv << ["Call ID", "Caller Name", "Caller Phone", "Call Created At", "Call Status", "Incident Number", "Diagnosis", "Service Level", "Patient Name", "Patient Age", "Patient Sex", "Transfer From", "Transfer To", "Insurance", "Transfer Date", "Unit", "IMX Number"]
      all.each do |call|
        csv << [call.id, call.caller_name, call.caller_phone, call.created_at, call.call_status, call.incident_number, call.nature.determinant, call.service_level.level_of_service, call.patient_name, call.patient_age, call.patient_sex.sex, transfer_from_name(call), transfer_to_name(call), call.insurance.insurance_type, call.transfer_date, call.units.map(&:unit_name).join(", "), call.imx_num]
      end
    end
  end
```

index.html.erb

```
<h2>Reports</h2>
<%= render 'search'%>
<%= render 'results'%>
```

_search.html.erb

```
<div>
  <%= form_tag reports_path, :method => 'get' do %>  
    <p>
        <%= select_tag "search[type]", options_for_select([["All Statuses", "all"], ["Open", "open"], ["Closed", "closed"], ["Canceled", "canceled"], ["Wait & Return", "waitreturn"]], selected: params[:search].try(:[], :type)) %>
        <%= select_tag "search[service_level]", options_from_collection_for_select(ServiceLevel.order(:level_of_service), :level_of_service, :level_of_service, selected: params[:search].try(:[], :service_level)), prompt: "All Service Levels" %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= text_field_tag "search[start_date]", params[:search].try(:[], :start_date), :placeholder => 'Start Date', :class => 'input-large search-query ', id: 'start_date_select' %>
        to 
        <%= text_field_tag "search[end_date]", params[:search].try(:[], :end_date), :placeholder => 'End Date', :class => 'input-large search-query', id: 'end_date_select'   %>
      </p>

      <p>
        Unit
        <%= select_tag "search[unit_name]", options_from_collection_for_select(Unit.order(:unit_name), :unit_name, :unit_name, selected: params[:search].try(:[], :unit_name)), prompt: "Any Unit" %>

      </p>

      <p>
        From
        <%= select_tag "search[transferred_from]", options_from_collection_for_select(Facility.order(:facility_name), :id, :facility_name, selected: params[:search].try(:[], :transferred_from)), prompt: "Any Facility" %>
        To
      <%= select_tag "search[transferred_to]", options_from_collection_for_select(Facility.order(:facility_name), :id, :facility_name, selected: params[:search].try(:[], :transferred_to)), prompt: "Any Facility" %>
      </p> 

      <p>
        Results Per Page
        <%= select_tag "per_page", options_for_select([["10", 10], ["25", 25] , ["50", 50], ["100", 100], ["All", 100000]], selected: params[:per_page]), class: "span1" %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, :class => 'btn' %>
      </p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

_results.html.erb

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Incident Number</th>
      <th>Patient Name</th>
      <th>Transfer Date</th>
      <th>Transferred From</th>
      <th>Transferred To</th>
      <th>Determinant</th>
      <th>Unit</th>
      <th>Insurance</th>
      <th>Cancelation Reason</th>
      <th>IMX Number</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @calls.each do |c| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= c.incident_number %></td>
        <td><%= c.patient_name %></td>
        <td><%= c.transfer_date.strftime("%m/%d/%y") %></td>
        <td><%= transferred_from(c) %><br/><%= transferred_from_address(c) %></td>
        <td><%= transferred_to(c) %><br/><%= transferred_to_address(c) %></td>
        <td><%= c.nature.try(:determinant)%></td>
        <td><%= c.units.map(&:unit_name).join(", ") %></td>
        <td><%= c.insurance.try(:insurance_type)%></td>
        <td><%= c.cancel_reason.try(:reason) %></td>
        <td><%= c.imx_num %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'View', c, :class => 'btn btn-close btn-mini'%></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<%= will_paginate @calls, :renderer => BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
```

Comment: Whats your HTML code to call the CSV page?

Comment: I'm using this to generate a CSV file for download and it seems to be working using params.merge: *<%= link_to "Export Results to CSV", reports_path(params.merge(format: "csv")), :class => "btn btn-info" %>*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Call#to_csv` method you have:

```
all.each do |call|
        csv << [call.id, call.caller_name, call.caller_phone, call.created_at, call.call_status, call.incident_number, call.nature.determinant, call.service_level.level_of_service, call.patient_name, call.patient_age, call.patient_sex.sex, transfer_from_name(call), transfer_to_name(call), call.insurance.insurance_type, call.transfer_date, call.units.map(&:unit_name).join(", "), call.imx_num]
      end
```

I'm thinking the `all` is what is loading up the entire data-set, not your filtered version.

How about passing in the actual rows to convert to CSV, like:

```
def self.to_csv(records = [], options = {})
    CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
      csv << ["Call ID", "Caller Name", "Caller Phone", "Call Created At", "Call Status", "Incident Number", "Diagnosis", "Service Level", "Patient Name", "Patient Age", "Patient Sex", "Transfer From", "Transfer To", "Insurance", "Transfer Date", "Unit", "IMX Number"]
      records.each do |call|
        csv << [call.id, call.caller_name, call.caller_phone, call.created_at, call.call_status, call.incident_number, call.nature.determinant, call.service_level.level_of_service, call.patient_name, call.patient_age, call.patient_sex.sex, transfer_from_name(call), transfer_to_name(call), call.insurance.insurance_type, call.transfer_date, call.units.map(&:unit_name).join(", "), call.imx_num]
      end
    end
  end
```

And then updating your controller:

```
format.csv { send_data Call.to_csv(@calls }
```

Comment: Ok I tried this.  By doing it this way, it still exports all of the call records ignoring the search query.  Also had to add a ) to format.csv { send_data Call.to_csv(@calls) }in the controller to make it work.  You had a syntax error I think.  I guess I'm not understanding how to pass the search params to the to_csv method.  The way you described it is only exporting all of the calls.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not passing the search params to the `to_csv` method. You're using `Call.report` to generate the filtered set and then passing the records to `to_csv` just to be massaged into the desired CSV format. In other words, `to_csv` should NOT be doing any fetching of its own - you just pass it previously fetched records to massage for display

Comment: I'm following you now.  So in my view code how would I make a button to generate a CSV of the filtered results?  I was using: *<%= link_to "CSV", reports_path(format: "csv"), :class => "btn btn-info" %>* but it just exports all the calls instead of the instance variable @calls.

Comment: I think I figured it out.  *<%= link_to "Export Results to CSV", reports_path(params.merge(format: "csv")), :class => "btn btn-info" %>* seems to export only the specific search results.  Does this sound right?

Comment: @shakycode, your comment is the answer, the existing answer needs editing

Answer (score 4):

In my view this is the code that needs to persist the params and merge them.

```
 <%= link_to "Export Results to CSV", reports_path(params.merge(format: "csv")), :class => "btn btn-info" %>
```

Note the `params.merge` which takes all of the selected params, merges them, and passes them to the controller.

Comment: That's the one I needed for my excel output. great!

Answer (score 0):

`params.merge` works wonders in situations like these. Also , having two submit buttons for the form works. For example, one being an export csv.